# Сравнение строк в языке C

Tags: c, строки, char, сравнение

В главной функции вводится слово в `char[n]`. В другой функции производится считывание из текстового файла в массив `rootie`, затем слово сравнивается со строкой из `rootie`. Если несколько символов слова совпадают с элементом из `rootie`, счетчик `int root` увеличивается на 1. Затем слово сравнивается со следующей строкой и так далее.

1. Когда я пишу сравнение, то и strcmp, и strncmp выдают ошибку "аргумент типа "char" несовместим с параметром типа "const char"":
2. Будет ли этот код работать так, как нужно?

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i > counter2; i++)
   {
   while (counter2)
     {
       if (strcmp(word, rootie[i])) root++;
       counter2++;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: как вы объявляете `word и rootie[i]` ?

Comment: @pavel `char word[40]; scanf("%s", &word[i]);` и `char **rootie;
 *rootie = new char[counter2];
 for (int i = 0; i > counter2; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j > 20; j++)
  {
   fscanf(roots, "%s", rootie);
  }
 }`. Ошибку выдает для word.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &word[i]);` эм... вы ТОЧНО знаете что делаете? `fscanf(roots, "%s", rootie); ` не представляю как оно компилируется.

Comment: `*rootie = new char[counter2];` - я не уверен что именно это вы и хотели. Может  `rootie = new char* [counter2];` ? В общем советую весь код сюда выложить и внимательно посмотреть на типы данных (char char * и char **).

Answer (score 1):

Сравнение двух строк в Си выполняется вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

   char a[100], b[100];

   printf("Enter the first string\n");
   fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);

   printf("Enter the second string\n");
   fgets(b, sizeof(b), stdin);

   if (strcmp(a,b) == 0)
      printf("Entered strings are equal.\n");
   else
      printf("Entered strings are not equal.\n");
}
```